# Export google satallite raster in QGIS 2.12- problem

Tags: qgis, raster, google-earth

When I import aerial raster from Google satellite, using the OpenLayers plugin

[image]

[image]

the raster is located in the right place.
But when I export it the raster isn't located in the right place:

[image]

I read [Problems exporting aerial imagery from QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126789/problems-exporting-aerial-imagery-from-qgis) and didn't find any suitable answer for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use EPSG:2039 for the project CRS.

As you can see, I've managed to reproduce your result.
[image]

Here are possible ways to solve the issue:

Set the project CRS to EPSG:3857 (WGS 84 Psuedo Mercator). This is the CRS that the Google satellite imagery is by default. It goes without saying that you should make sure it is defined that way.

Setting the CRS to EPSG:3857 results in a perfectly aligned road in EPSG:2039
[image]

Another option is to not use the Open Layers plugin as it has several issues. You can use the QuickMap Service as detailed in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172019/why-are-the-google-basemaps-no-longer-appearing-in-qgis)

Comment: how did you know i used EPSG:2039?

Comment: i also succeed in placing the road on the raster. the problem occur when i export it

Comment: @newGIS The on-the-fly projection of heavy basemaps is notoriously problematic. You are trying to project it to 2039, and while it may appear right on the map canvas, the transformation (Molodensky in this instance) doesn't hold when exporting. I observed a similar problem in ArcMap. The solution, like I said, adjust your project to match the heaviest file. As for how I knew you used 2039, I read you bio ;-)

Comment: thanks HDunn, i changed the CRS of the layer into 3857-still, in the export- the layer moved aside to a worng place- how can i solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

finally, i found this solution:

I save the google base map by Project Menu--> Save as image. This image will be automatically with CRS. Then I load the image into the map and export the base map with other layer and the is no error in the map orientation.